# A sine product with (almost) integer values

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Let n, k be integers, $n>1$ and $k \perp n$ denote that k, n  are coprime and let $S_n = \{1 \le k \le \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor :  k  \perp n \}.$ Then 
$$ n \left( \prod_{k \in S_{n}} \sin \left( k \frac {\pi}{n} \right) \right)^{-2}  \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

I think this is surprising but I have no proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of results for products that are closely connected to your product.  There are some inessential differences (inverse is not taken), and generally products are over all $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$ relatively prime to $n$, but that would be taken care of by your squaring. [Here](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CDsQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmathdl.maa.org%2Fimages%2Fupload_library%2F22%2FAllendoerfer%2F1988%2F0025570x.di021149.02p0095y.pdf&ei=sN8ETt-kOu3TiAKSyImrDQ&usg=AFQjCNEIlfGwFkeDFyXNPw89hg6WNkaqgQ&sig2=eUc32sUTKFg5tEu1b9-2ow) is a link to a fully available paper by Steven Galovich.

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice and highly relevant paper. Yes, I think the above formula can be justified by Galovich's theorems.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas I tried clicking on the link you provided, but the page is not found. Would you kindly provide an updated link to this paper by Steven Galovich? Thank you,

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Also, would you know of any other formulas similar to the one posted of (almost) integer values? If you could provide them or point me in their direction I would be grateful. Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians You can try here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690306?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @user Many thanks.