# Are There Some Other Sine Products with Almost Integer Values?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, trigonometry, special-functions, approximation

In a post several years ago---

[A sine product with (almost) integer values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47441/a-sine-product-with-almost-integer-values/47447#47447)

a user observed that under some certain conditions,

$$ n \left( \prod_{k \in S_{n}} \sin \left( k \frac {\pi}{n} \right) \right)^{-2}  $$

is (almost) an integer.

Another user offered a link to an (unnamed) paper by S. Galovich, but the link has since expired. Does anyone know of which of Galovich's papers may have contained theorem(s) pertaining to the above observation? (Galovich is now deceased.) Also, does anyone know of other similar products involving the sine function or any other trigonometric functions that might produce ``almost'' integer values? Thanks.

Comment: I've looked for the document, and it think it should be this one: (products of sines and cosines, Steven Galovich, Math magazine, Vol 60, No 2, April 1987); https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1987.11977283

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2777933

Comment: @user Thank you for this link.

Comment: @Sudix Thank you. I look forward to obtaining the whole paper.